# How to add class and id attributes to lithium form helper?

Tags: forms, lithium

I'm using the [Form Helper](http://lithify.me/docs/lithium/template/helper/Form) in Lithium and wonder how to add the HTML attributes `class` and `id` to the output of `$this->form->create();`? I want to set these attributes on the `form` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As intuitive as `$this->form->create(null, ['class' => 'foo', 'id' => 'bar'])`

NB: replace `null` with `$something` if you are binding an object to the form.

Comment: Thanks - somehow this didn't work for 20 minutes as I tried variations of this :/ But/And I think it must be `$this->form->create(null, array('class' => 'foo', 'id' => 'bar'))`.

Comment: yep that depends on your php version and array syntax ;-)